# Nginx Location matching regex

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting, location

Guys please help me to cover all the tm*.html pages in my location math

location /tacticalsales/tm(.*).html$ {
}

Cannot get the wildcard to work. Please also add some explanation on this or refer to documenation. Thanks

Also please help with ading regex for numbers only.. somehting like this [1-10] instead of (.*) should work?

Comment: Ok Answering on my question location ~ ^/tacticalsales/tm[1-9].html$ {
this works for nubmers...  but need to now alternative for * wildcard macthing

Comment: Well This one is good location ~ "^/tacticalsales/tm([1-9]|10).html$"  

But I need to cover also the pages like tm5hjdf.html or tm6c.html

Answer (score 2):

It's not 100% clear what you're asking for (this might be down to me), but I've tried to answer as best as possible

```
^((tacticalsales\/)?tm([0-9]|10).*?\.html)$
```

This will match on the three examples that you have given (tm5hjdf.html & tm6c.html) as well as if they're prefixed with tacticalsales/.

Hope this helps!